# Как запустить модуль vars_prompt внутри роли?

Tags: linux, администрирование, ansible, devops, yaml

Подскажите. Я при запуске  playbook с ролями собираю данные (vars_prompt), дальше в конкретных ролях беру эти переменные. Но мне не всегда нужно собирать данные или все данные, но запуская playbook все равно читается весь файл и запускаются модули vars_prompt.

Можно ли его(vars_prompt) прописать конкретно в РОЛЬ, что бы только если небходимо выполнить конкретную роль из нее запускался vars_ptompt?

У меня не взлетело из роли!
Или как интерактвно собирать данные врутри роли?

```
**site.yml**

 - hosts: server
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
    ssh_key: "input password for ssh"
  roles:
    - server_1
    - server_2
    - server_got

- hosts: client
  become: yes
  vars_prompt:
    role_name: "input rolname"
  roles:
    - client_1
    - client_2
    - client_boss
```

```
*role/server/tasks/main.yml*

- name: Add password
  debconf:
    name: pkg_name
    question: ssh_key
    value: "{{ssh_key}}"
    vtype: password
  tags:
    - pkg_name
    - server

- name: install pkg_name
  apt: name=pkg_name state=present allow_unauthenticated=yes update_cache=yes
  tags:
    - pkg_name
    - server
```

Comment: А какая версия ансибла?

Comment: О, как....2.2.1

Comment: Ну я бы не сказал, что прям сильный свежак. https://github.com/ansible/ansible щас 2.9.6 актуальная. При чём если посмотреть по бранчам - каждая даже минорщина вносила столько нового, что просто долбануться. Обновляйся.